# All users in "to" field receive read receipt

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, terminal-services

I have a couple of users that when sending a read receipt everyone in the To field gets a read receipt from everyone who read the email. This is a problem that only started recently.

The users are using Outlook 2010 in a Terminal Services session. The server is running Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard and the client OS is Windows 7 Professional.

I am unable to see if this is something being caused the the email server, as they use a third-party email host to provide email and we do not have access to logs, etc.